# Movie from the 1960's where aliens are seen only through glasses

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can remember seeing a sci-fi film on TV (from 1960's) over here in the UK. Aliens could only been seen through glasses and a man gave a woman a pill to calm her down before she put them on.

I can't find the name of the film though.

Comment: Are you sure about the time frame of the movie? I don't recall a bit about a tablet (it's been years since I've seen it), but the general plot sounds like [They Live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/They_Live)

Comment: Agree with phantom42, glasses bit sure sounds like They Live.  Time frame is 1988 though and I don't recall a tablet either (but also been a long time since I've seen it).  See another proposal has just been provided as an answer.  If neither of these are it, additional details would be helpful.

Comment: I changed the word "tablet" to "pill".  Feel free to change it back if it is the wrong word, but "tablet" seemed to be causing some confusion.

Comment: Where was there confusion over "tablet"?

Comment: It's the Love War circa 1970.

Comment: @phantom42 Well, I was confused.  I read tablet and thought of a portable computing device.

Comment: @TGnat LOL, what is our world coming to? Yesterday someone told me to remove a web from a corner in the room, I thought they meant a web page.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211436/60s-70s-sci-fi-film-where-two-competing-alien-races-send-agents-disguised-as-hum (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 24):

Is it "[The Love War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Love_War)" from 1970?

It's about warring aliens on earth and they can see each other only by using special glasses.

> *Two warring planets choose to settle their conflict over which of them will take over the planet Earth; by each sending a trio of
>   soldiers to the Earth, to do personal combat to the death. The loser's
>   planet cedes the conquest of the earth to the winner of the combat.
>   The combatants, disguised as human beings, can only identify each
>   other by using special visors.*

[image]

Comment: The OP is definitely referring to 'The Love War'. I remember seeing it sometime in the early 1970s. I could recall the need for glasses, the woman questioning why the man was always wearing the glasses in a hotel room and the fact I was convinced that the star was Lloyd Bridges. I've been looking for the name of this film for years!

Comment: At first I thought the OP was describing a scene from "The Invaders" (1967) TV show. But I do recall the movie and mainly remember the ending (which I confirmed from the wiki page link above). So I am sure this is the movie (The Love War) the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 23):

One name that comes to mind is **[They Live](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096256/)** from the year **1988**.

I remember that he could also see subliminal messages (in black and white) in all the advertising and some other things as well, but I cannot remember the tablet event which you mentioned. I cannot recall a similar movie from the 60's, but this may have been a remake of the same.

[image]